# NoMethod error for Capybara without Rails,Rspec or Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara, saucelabs

I'm trying to run Capybara without Rails,Cucumber,Rspec just in pure Ruby.

My test script looks like this:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

url = "MyAccessKey"
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
capabilities.platform = :LINUX

Capybara.register_driver :sauce do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
  :browser => :remote, :url => url,
  :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
end

Capybara.default_driver=:sauce
Capybara.app_host="127.0.0.1:8888"


include Capybara::DSL
# include Capybara::RSpecMatchers

visit('')
feature "Signing in" do
    scenario "Should sign in" do
        within ('#form_content') do
            fill_in 'login',:with=>'user'
            fill_in 'password',:with=>'pwd'
            find(:xpath,'//input[@type="submit"]').click    
        end
    end
end
```

`visit` works fine... but `feature and scenario` gives a NoMethodError. Should I include anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feature` and `scenario` are part of RSpec. This is not loaded by default when using Capybara.

Assuming you want to include the Capybara modified RSpec, instead of doing:

```
require 'capybara'
```

Do:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

If you just want plain RSpec, you can of course do:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'rspec'
```